# How to filter Browsers UserAgents with PHP?

Tags: php, browser

I want to have a PHP Code where I could filter 3 different Browsers : FF/Chrome/IE.

I want it so that if its FF and Chrome, it doesnt load an iframe on the website. If its IE, it should load the iframe.

I suppose I should work with the user agents. Any advices on this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '(compatible; MSIE ')!==FALSE) {
   //FOR IE
}
```

more info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for browser capabilities rather than user agents, as user agent faking is as simple as installing an add-on for most common browsers.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php has some pretty good information, and do note that even this stuff can be faked if someone really wants to.